# How to check whether MatSnackBar is opened?

Tags: angular

Whenever there are errors, the snack bar should be opened, else it is dismissed. I want to test this,

```
 handleErrors(error: ErrorMessage): void {
this.snackBar.open(error.message, '', {
  duration: 15000
})
}

routeToTallyConfig() {
 this.router.navigateByUrl(ROUTE_TALLY_CONFIG)
}

onStateChange(state) {
if (Util.isNotNull(state)) {
  // check errors
  if (Util.isNotNull(state.error)) {
    this.loader.display(false)
    this.handleErrors(state.error)
  } else {
    // no errors
    this.loader.display(false)
    if (Util.isNotNull(state.user) && Util.isNotNull(state.user.id)) {
      this.routeToTallyConfig()
    }
  }
}
}
```

In my tests, I will call the `onStateChange()` function by passing different values for state. On passing error, the snackbar should be displayed and it should be dismissed if there is no error. How can I test this behaviour in angular 4?

Comment: Assign snackbar as variable. So let snackBarRef = snackBar.open('Message archived');  and then  
snackBarRef.afterDismissed().subscribe(() => { this.detector=false //ofcorse declare this above constructor }); so now check if this.detector is true, if true you have snack bar open so you can close it, snackBarRef.dismiss(); sourse https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I assume you set up the Test bed and mocked all of your dependencies)

You don't actually test **if the snack is opened**, you test if **the snack open function has been called**. It's not your job to test if a dependency works, it's the dependency's job.

This means that if you want to test if the snacker is called, you must do :

```
it('handleErrors should open the snacker', () => {
  spyOn(component.snackBar, 'open');
  component.handleErrors({message: 'error'} as any);
  expect(component.snackBar.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith('error', '', {duration: 1500});
});
```

On the opposite, you can also test if the snacker hasn't been called with

```
  spyOn(component.snackBar, 'open');
  // Tests ...
  expect(component.snackBar.open).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Why are you snackbar service and handleError function public? They should only be controlled within your app and then your tests would fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can check _openedSnackBarRef snackbar's getter property. It returns MatSnackBarRef if it is opened and null otherwise